# xcode iphone simulator - no dummy location

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, core-location

I have an app that uses the core location services. It works perfectly fine on an iPhone device, but sometimes I want to test it on the simulator and in that case, I need Xcode to send some fake locations to the simulator.

So I use the 'Debug > Simulate location' feature choosing **London** or **San Francisco** as I have always done, but nothing happens! my `didUpdateToLocation` method is never called!

I saw that before (again only on the simulator) and I assumed Xcode was a bit buggy but now I just can't get any location.

Is there some obscure settings I may have changed somewhere?

(I use `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers` and `kCLDistanceFilterNone`).

Again, it is a simulator-only issue.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is embarrassing, it is due to the fact I said 'no' a couple of days ago when the question 'would you like app X to access your location?' appeared in the app.

So, if you have the same issue, that might be worth deleting the app completely from the simulator and reinstalling it to get asked that question again (and answer 'yes' this time).

Oh well, will probably delete this stack overflow question...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to set latitude longitude value in simulator like
debug -> location ->custom location and your simulator work like whatever lat long set is your current position.